Remove/reduce the intensity of the fade of the Desert Tikzposter theme
Is there a way to remove or reduce the fade in tikzposter's Desert theme (block and main title)? It gets visually uncomfortable to read when the text approaches the end of the fade.

MWE :
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, blockverticalspace=1.6cm]{tikzposter}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{paperwidth=914mm,paperheight=1219mm}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering bla bla title \\ bla bla subtitle}}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Institution}

\usetheme{Desert}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{
    \fontsize{55}{70}\selectfont
    Title gets uncomfortable if too long
    }
    {
        \fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont
        \blindtext
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{
    \fontsize{55}{70}\selectfont
    Title gets uncomfortable if too long
    }
    {
        \fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont
        \blindtext
    }
\end{columns}
\end{document}


You can change the title and block styles like this (adjust the value of !50! to make the gradient more or less pronounced):
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, blockverticalspace=1.6cm]{tikzposter}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{paperwidth=914mm,paperheight=1219mm}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering bla bla title \\ bla bla subtitle}}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Institution}

\definetitlestyle{VerticalShading}{
    width=\paperwidth, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0pt, innersep=1.5cm,
    titletotopverticalspace=0mm, titletoblockverticalspace=20mm,
    titlegraphictotitledistance=10pt, titletextscale=1
}{
   \draw[draw=none, bottom color=framecolor!50!titlebgcolor, top color=titlebgcolor]%
   (\titleposleft,\titleposbottom) rectangle (\titleposright,\titlepostop); %
}


\defineblockstyle{Slide}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titleleft,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=0pt,
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0pt, titleinnersep=1cm,
    bodyinnersep=1cm
}{
    \ifBlockHasTitle%
        \draw[draw=none, left color=blocktitlebgcolor, right color=blockbodybgcolor!50!blocktitlebgcolor]
           (blocktitle.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
    \fi%
    \draw[draw=none, fill=blockbodybgcolor] %
        (blockbody.north west) [rounded corners=30] -- (blockbody.south west) --
        (blockbody.south east) [rounded corners=0]-- (blockbody.north east) -- cycle;
}


\usetheme{Desert}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{
    \fontsize{55}{70}\selectfont
    Title gets uncomfortable if too long
    }
    {
        \fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont
        \blindtext
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{
    \fontsize{55}{70}\selectfont
    Title gets uncomfortable if too long
    }
    {
        \fontsize{50}{70}\selectfont
        \blindtext
    }
\end{columns}
\end{document}



Works like a charm, thank you !

@UserBoy You're welcome!
